Method 'System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName' not found when compiling Maui iOS app
I have a MAUI C# app that compiles and runs on Windows and Android. Now i am trying to compile on iOS Simulator. I get the error shown below. I have tried placing the PNG file in the Resources\AppIcon, Resources\Images and root folders. Yet, I still get the same error. I am suspecting that it is unrelated to the placement of the file.
What am I missing here?
MSB4186 Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(C:\MyProjLocation\obj\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\resizetizer\r\Assets.xcassets\appicon.appiconset\appiconItunesArtwork.png)". Method 'System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(a, b)). Check that all parameters are defined, are of the correct type, and are specified in the right order.   SiddurHaGra (net8.0-ios)

Please check  does thsi file exists in pyour project. Another thing check that your XCAssets - >AppIcon.appiconset file contains appiconItunesArtwork.png file ?

the file is in the project.... there is a ...\obj\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\resizetizer\r\Assets.xcassets folder after the (failed) build. and  there is an appiconItunesArtwork.png file there...

Try to delete that file and check

@Moshe Raab, make sure for all Image names must be lowercase

deleted the folder, same error. file copied to the new folder

Changes to Image will not take effect until you Rebuild one\twice

deleted folders, renamed to lower case. the file was created in the XCAssets folder with mixed case! i don't understand what is happening! and the PNG is the correct image

Check your project configuration, double click on it, you must not include Image twice . Implicitly from <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" /> and explicitly by <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\myimage.png" />

it appears only once, but i did notice that the project file does have a MauiImage Remove :

...



...
 





Create a minimal reproducible on GitHub

Do you want to Add an app icon to a .NET MAUI app project? Does it happen in a default project?

This is not a real answer, but...
When i commented out these lines in .nuget\packages\microsoft.maui.resizetizer\8.0.40\buildTransitive\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.After.targets file. i was able to compile and install the debug version on my iPad. there was no program icon.
SO the Nuget file is defining something about the images... so where in my app am i supposed to place them? it did not help in the root, nor in Resources\AppIcon nor in Resources\Images
Contains('Assets.xcassets'))' == 'True' and '%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Identity)' != ''">
          Assets.xcassets\$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Identity)))))\%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Filename)%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Extension)
          Assets.xcassets\$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Identity)))))\%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Filename)%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Extension)
          Assets.xcassets\$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Identity)))))\%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Filename)%(_ResizetizerCollectedBundleResourceImages.Extension)
      
